# Add 2 different variables in a variable, not concatenation

Tags: php

```
$user_subject = 'new order';
$email_us = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name_us = $_REQUEST['name'];
$phone_us = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$qut = $_REQUEST['qut'];
$message_us = $_REQUEST['message'];
$email = "email@website.com";
$message = '<HTML><body dir="rtl">';
.
.
.
.
if(mail($email, $user_subject, $message, $headers)) {
$mess_err = "Successful message";  
}
```

I am trying to send a message to multiple e-mails. I have tried:

```
$email = "email@website.com"; "email2@website.com"; 
// in this case is taking first one only

$email = array("email@website.com", "email2@website.com");
// in this case it send me an error like: Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

tried also converting it to string:

```
$emails = array("email@website.com", "email2@website.com");
$email = array_shift($emails);

// in this case doesn't work at all
```

Please help me on this. I need to send a message to 2 emails instead of 1. How do i do this?

Comment: are you using phpmailer? Or better, which method are you using to send the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$emails = array("email@website.com", "email2@website.com");
$email = array_shift($emails);
```

try this:

```
$emails = array("email@website.com", "email2@website.com");
$email = implode(",",$emails);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [PHP mail documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), you have to use string concatenation, it seems.

From the docs:

> The formatting of this string must comply with » RFC 2822. Some
> examples are:
>
> - user@example.com
> - user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
> - User <user@example.com>
> - User <user@example.com>,Another User <anotheruser@example.com>

You can concatenate strings with a dot:

```
$email = $email1 . "," . $email2;
```

or, if you have the emails in an array, you can use `join`:

```
$addresses = array("email1@example.com", "email2@example.com");
$email = join(",", $addresses);
```

which will then set `$email` to `email1@example.com,email2@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
mail("mail1@site.com , mail2@site.com , mail3@site.com","subject","message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple recepients will be comma separated, like so-

```
$email_id = "email@website.com, email2@website.com";
```

If $email_ids is an array of email ids, then

```
$email_id = implode(', ',$email_ids);
```